# convert POST array data to json format

Tags: php

I'm using POST Method and I want the PHP script to return the data in JSON format

//data 1:

```
<input type="text" value="1" name="id[]">
<input type="text" value="aa" name="name[]">
<input type="text" value="cc" name="stuff[]">
```

//data 2:

```
<input type="text" value="2" name="id[]">
<input type="text" value="dd" name="name[]">
<input type="text" value="ff" name="stuff[]">
```

**i want result be like  :**

```
{id:1,name:"aa",stuff:"cc"},{id:2,name:"dd",stuff:"ff"}
```

I understand that if we use json_encode($_POST,true)  i will have :

```
{"id":["1","2"],"name":["aa","dd"],"stuff":["cc","ff"]}
```

i can do that with js using get method **not** post

```
id[]=1&name[]=aa&stuff=cc&id[]=2&name[]=dd&stuff[]=ff
```

Check my solution
 https://jsfiddle.net/cqvny3th/

Or what if  we generate url from the post method using **http_build_query**, result is :

```
id[]=1&id[]=2&name[]=aa&name[]=dd&stuff=cc&stuff[]=ff
```

But my solution works only with :

```
id[]=1&name[]=aa&stuff=cc&id[]=2&name[]=dd&stuff[]=ff
```

Regards

Comment: That first result isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely less elegant than @Don't Panic's solution, but in case you want/need to keep your `name` attributes as they are, this will work:

```
//prep
$repeated_post_vars = ['id', 'name', 'stuff'];
$arr = [];

//find which column has the most values, just in case they're not all equal
$num_items = max(array_map(function($col) {
    return !empty($_POST[$col]) ? count($_POST[$col]) : 0;
}, $repeated_post_vars));

//iterate over value sets
for ($g=0; $g<$num_items; $g++) {
    foreach($repeated_post_vars as $col)
        $tmp[$col] = !empty($_POST[$col][$g]) ? $_POST[$col][$g] : null;
    $arr[] = $tmp;
}
```

So if `$_POST` on submit looks like:

```
[
    'id' => [1, 2],
    'name' => ['foo', 'bar'],
    'stuff' => [3]
];
```

The code produces:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"foo","stuff":3},{"id":2,"name":"bar","stuff":null}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Rename your inputs, if you can.

```
<input type="text" value="1" name="data1[id]">
<input type="text" value="aa" name="data1[name]">
<input type="text" value="cc" name="data1[stuff]">

<input type="text" value="2" name="data2[id]">
<input type="text" value="dd" name="data2[name]">
<input type="text" value="ff" name="data2[stuff]">
```

That will group the data properly. Use `array_values` before `json_encode` so you'll get an array of objects rather than an object.

```
echo json_encode(array_values($_GET));
```

Comment: Literally never knew you could do that. Wow, every day's a school day.

Comment: I'm sure I must have learned this somewhere on Stack Overflow at some point. :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```
$list = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['id']); $i++) {
    $item = new stdClass();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $values)
        $item->{$key} = $values[$i];
    $list[] = $item;
}

print json_encode( $list );
```